# Python multithreading I/O operation

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tqdm

I am trying to multithread a simple application using python. It consists in loading a large amount of data from a format, treating it and saving it infos from this in a csv format with the help of `panda`. Basically here is a symbolic code for it:

```py
def read(time):
 #reagind it from a I/O lib format

def treat(time):
 #performing scipy operations

def write(time):
 #write it thanks to pandas
 df.to_csv(f'partial_{time}_data.csv')

def thread(time):
  read(time)
  load(time)
  write(time)

if __name__ = "__main__":
 schedule = [ list of times to load, treat and write ]
 #single thread version
 for time in schedule:
  thread(time)

 #pooling version
 from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map
 process_map(thread, schedule, max_workers=16)
```

IIUC `process_map` from tqdm uses `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` under the hood.
I was surprised to gain only a 2x on the observed execution time running it on a 8-core Intel processor. Is there a more clever way to leverage multiprocessing resources here ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Based on your breakdown, it would appear  you spend most of your time in `load`, which seems to be CPU-bound. Threads only let you interleave I/O that would otherwise block other code from running. Once you've read in the data, threads are just waisting time context-switching between different CPU tasks that could be spent actually using the CPU.

Comment: What is pandas doing to add value here?

Comment: pandas here is not doing much just leveraging it to write into csv. Do you think it could be slowing down the process ?

Comment: @chepner Do you suggest to use two different Pools, one for `read` and one for `treat/load` ?

Comment: If the bulk of your running time is spent doing things that don't involve waiting for I/O, then threads will not (significantly) speed up your program. Threads are for improving *concurrency*, not parallelism.

Comment: isn't `multiprocessing` parallelism ?

Comment: If multiprocessing speeds up CPU-bound operations, the next bottleneck becomes I/O-bound operations. Generally speaking, I/O-bound operations do not speed up by increasing the number of processes. Rather, on devices like HDDs, having too many processes can actually slow things down.

Comment: You are really indenting using just one space?